# How do I update the quantity without duplicate in redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have the add and Remove items state and it sends to the cart. Im my cart, when I add, it duplicates. Do I need to create a reducer for this increment so it can update from 1 to 2 instead of duplicating it?

```
const INITIAL_STATE = []

export const addItem = createAction('ADD_ITEM')
export const increment = createAction('INCREMENT')

export const removeItem = createAction('REMOVE_ITEM')

export default createReducer(INITIAL_STATE, {
  [addItem.type]: (state, action) => [...state, action.payload],
  [removeItem.type]: (state, action) => state.filter(item => item._id !== action.payload._id)
})
```

Here is my products:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = []

export const addProducts = createAction('ADD_PRODUCTS')
export const addProduct = createAction('ADD_PRODUCT')

export default createReducer(INITIAL_STATE, {
  [addProducts.type]: (state , action) => [...state, action.payload],
  [addProduct.type]: (state, action) => [...action.payload]
})
```

My reducer:

```
export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    products: productsReducer,
    cart: cartReducer
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Quantity

Right now your `cart` state is saving an array of all of the items that are in the cart. There is no `quantity` property anywhere.  One thing that you could do is add a `quantity: 1` property to the item object when you add that item to the cart. But...

#### Normalizing State

You don't really need to save the while `item` object because you already have that information in `products`.  All that you really need to know is the `id` of each item in the cart and its `quantity`.  The most logical data structure for that is a dictionary object where the keys are the item ids and the values are the corresponding quantities.

Since you only need the `id` I would recommend that your action creators `addItem`, `removeItem` and `increment` should just be a function of the `id` instead of the whole `item`.  This means that you would call them like `dispatch(addItem(5))` and your `action.payload` would just be the `id`. The `addProduct` and `addProducts` actions still need the whole `item` object.

An array of products is fine and you can always call `state.products.find(item => item._id === someId)` to find a product by its id.  But a keyed object is better!  You want to have the keys be the item ids and the values be the corresponding objects.  Redux Toolkit has built-in support for this structure with the [`createEntityAdapter`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createEntityAdapter) helper.

#### Create Slice

There's not any problem with defining your actions though `createAction`, but it's not needed.  You can replace `createAction` and `createReducer` with [`createSlice`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice) which combines the functionality of both.

Here's another way of writing your products:

```
import { createSlice, createEntityAdapter } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const productsAdapter = createEntityAdapter({
  selectId: (item) => item._id
});

const productsSlice = createSlice({
  // this becomes the prefix for the action names
  name: "products",
  // use the initial state from the adapter
  initialState: productsAdapter.getInitialState(),
  // your case reducers will create actions automatically
  reducers: {
    // you can just pass functions from the adapter
    addProduct: productsAdapter.addOne,
    addProducts: productsAdapter.addMany
    // you can also add delete and update actions easily
  }
});

export default productsSlice.reducer;
export const { addProduct, addProducts } = productsSlice.actions;

// the adapter also creates selectors
const productSelectors = productsAdapter.getSelectors(
  // you need to provide the location of the products relative to the root state
  (state) => state.products
);

// you can export the selectors individually
export const {
  selectById: selectProductById,
  selectAll: selectAllProducts
} = productSelectors;
```

And your cart:

```
import {createSlice, createSelector} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'cart',
  // an empty dictionary object
  initialState: {},
  reducers: {
    addItem: (state, action) => {
      const id = action.payload;
      // add to the state with a quantity of 1
      state[id] = 1;
      // you might want to see if if already exists before adding
    },
    removeItem: (state, action) => {
      const id = action.payload;
      // you can just use the delete keyword to remove it from the draft
      delete state[id];
    },
    increment: (state, action) => {
      const id = action.payload;
      // if you KNOW that the item is already in the state then you can do this
      state[id]++;
      // but it's safer to do this
      // state[id] = (state[id] || 0) + 1
    }
  }
})

export default cartSlice.reducer;
export const {addItem, removeItem, increment} = cartSlice.actions;

// you can select the data in any format
export const selectCartItems = createSelector(
  // only re-calculate when this value changes
  state => state.cart,
  // reformat into an an array of objects with propeties id and quantity
  (cart) => Object.entries(cart).map(([id, quantity]) => ({id, quantity}))
)

// select the quantity for a particular item by id
export const selectQuantityById = (state, id) => state.cart[id]

// you can combine the ids with the products, but 
// I actually recommend that you just return the ids and get the
// product data from a Product component like <Product id={5} quantity={2}/>
export const selectCartProducts = createSelector(
  // has two input selectors
  state => state.cart,
  state => state.products,
  // combine and reformat into an array of objects
  (cart, products) => Object.keys(cart).map(id => ({
    // all properties of the product
    ...products.entries[id],
    // added quantity property
    quantity: cart[id],
  }))
)
```

Comment: I was calling the function like this:```function addItemCart(item){
    dispatch(addItem(item))
    console.log('add', item);
  }```

Comment: Where do I call the function to add? I mean, I just started with redux yesterday.

Comment: It would be the `onClick` property of some `button` or other element.  `<button onClick={() => dispatch(addItem(item._id))}>Add To Cart</button>`

Comment: And how can I fetch my products and Set so addProducts? I was using ```export const getProducts = (id, index) => {
  return dispatch => {
    axios.get(`https://api-test-carrinho.herokuapp.com/product/business/${id}`)
      .then(res => {
        dispatch(addProducts(res.data.data))
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch(console.log)
  }
}```

Comment: Use createAsyncThunk — it will handle pending, fulfilled, and error actions https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk.

Answer (score 2):

It would be necessary that your reducer verify if the item ID exists or not. Case exists, update the item count. Instead of, create a new item with count equal to 1:

```
export default createReducer(INITIAL_STATE, {
  [addItem.type]: (state, action) => {
    const pos = state.map((i) => i._id).indexOf(action.payload._id);
    if (pos !== -1) {
      state[pos] = { ...action.payload, count: state[pos].count + 1 };
    } else {
      state.push({ ...action.payload, count: 1 });
    }
  },
  [removeItem.type]: (state, action) =>
    state.filter((item) => item._id !== action.payload._id),
});
```

Comment: They are using the [`createReducer`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer) function from Redux Toolkit which uses a mutable draft state, so actually you don't need to clone anything.  If you don't mind I'm going to edit your answer because you can do basically the same thing in Redux Toolkit but without the clone and without the `return`.

Comment: @LindaPaiste I didn't know about this behaviour... very good! Thanks!

Comment: @LindaPaiste "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot convert undefined or null to object" when I try to use ```export const fetchProducts = createAsyncThunk(
  'products/fetchProducts',
  async (id, { dispatch }) => {
    return axios.get(`https://api-test-carrinho.herokuapp.com/product/business/${id}`
    ).then(resp => {
      dispatch(addProduct(resp.data))
    })
  }
)```

Comment: But when I use addProductS, it shows a warning with the values but empty in the console.